# How to access a variable that is inside a function?

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I know this may sound like a duplicate question but I have tried a zillion things form Stack Overflow already and it does not work. What I am trying to do involves noUiSlider and I am trying to basically get the 3 values of each slider and then use those values any way I wish - for example to turn on or off a next button if the total value of the sliders adds up to a given value.

Here's the code in question:

```
    // On document ready, initialize noUiSlider.
      $(function(){



        $('.guardsRanger').noUiSlider({
          start: [0],
          step: 1,
          behaviour: 'tap-drag',
          range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 8
          }
        }, true);

        $('.jacksRanger').noUiSlider({
          start: [0],
          step: 1,
          behaviour: 'tap-drag',
          range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 8
          }
        }, true);

        $('.strikersRanger').noUiSlider({
          start: [0],
          step: 1,
          behaviour: 'tap-drag',
          range: {
            'min': 0,
            'max': 8
          }
        }, true);

        $("#pips-values").noUiSlider_pips({
  mode: 'values',
  values: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  density: 8
});

        $("#pips1-values").noUiSlider_pips({
  mode: 'values',
  values: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  density: 8
});

        $("#pips2-values").noUiSlider_pips({
  mode: 'values',
  values: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  density: 8
});


var guardsval;


$(".guardsRanger").on({
  set: function(){
    guardsval = $(".guardsRanger").val();
  }
});

$(".jacksRanger").on({
  set: function(){
    jacksval = $(".jacksRanger").val();
  }
});

$(".strikersRanger").on({
  set: function(){
    strikersval = $(".strikersRanger").val();
  }
});

alert(guardsval);

      });
```

Comment: Well, as long as you define `guardsval` outside the functions, you should be able to modify it from within the scope of function.

Comment: I get "undefined" and (aka) it keeps referring back to the global variable, which is weird and frustrating.

Comment: can you post full code on a fiddle or here? Hard to really know otherwise. With your current code fragment you are just defining events but not triggering them. So it hits last line where guardsval is, as stated, not defined.

Comment: Updated the code though I am unsure how much that helps... :(

Comment: You are not putting the alert in the right place for one thing.  try defining var guardsval = 'foo'; and I bet the alert displays 'foo'

Comment: alternatively, put alert(guardsval) after guardsval gets set a value.

Comment: Oh I did: "trying to basically get the 3 values of each slider and then use those values any way I wish - for example to turn on or off a next button if the total value of the sliders adds up to a given value."

Comment: well then your question was already answered.... put the alert inside the callback

Comment: I need to add up the value of the 3 callbacks and use that final value for something else. Putting the alert in the callback solves my issue how?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zLhLqze7/    fiddle itself doesn't work since there is no HTML provided in the question....but there are the basics spelled out plainly.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. Been there, done that, it's fantastic that the 3 values get all put into the alert, but those variables are still unavailable outside the 3 functions, which is the actual problem as stated in the title of the thread. However, thanks for making an effort. Very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you do not understand the concept of callbacks in JavasScript.

Please read the following question:
[Can someone explain me the callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352486/can-someone-explain-me-the-callback-functions)

Your callback functions (they are set through the `set` attribute) manipulate the `guardsval` variable only when some event happens (in this case the `set` event, I guess). The problem is, that you call `alert(guardsval)`, when `guardsval` isn't initialized yet.

Comment: I get what you're saying, and no I am no javascript wizard, but this does not really get me any closer to a solution either. :|

Comment: We all were at that point, where we didn't understand callbacks. If  you just want a solution for your problem: call the `alert` function directly after you set the variable.

Comment: I keep wondering why nobody gets what I am trying to achieve here, and it's definitely not my English... Imagine a page that has 3 different sliders. If slider1's value and slider2's value and slider3's value add up to let's say 8, then the next button gets unhidden. Sounds so simple, yet still causes a lot of trouble because being able to call the alert (which is there just for debugging reasons) from inside the function does not provide a solution because I have to be able to hold on to those values and access them outside the 3 functions somehow.

Comment: It seems, you are still not getting what I said. Put a `console.log(guardsval)` (if you are familiar with a debugger) or `alert(guardsval)` at the beginning of each callback and click some buttons. Maybe this will help you to understand the problem.